# Recognise this Modern Uncial font?

Tags: font-identification, serif

When I was in practice back in the day, before computer-based type, recognising typefaces wasn't a problem.  I knew hundreds by sight, and the example books from the type houses were an excellent fallback reference when I was stumped. But now that everyone and their cousin's cat can kludge up a font (okay, that's hyperbole) I generally don't even try.

But I ran across a nice Modern Uncial being used as drop caps and I'd like to know what it is, if it actually has an existence separate from its use in the books where I found it.  I haven't tried to hunt it down myself and wouldn't want anyone else to spend any time either; I'm hoping only that someone will recognise it immediately, from having used it.

The underlying model is pretty standard 13th-14th century uncial as you can see by the A, B, M, and S.  The distinctive chars are the C, which breaks serifing, the G which is out of proportion, and the W, which is the double-V type.

Except for the C, I can practically feel my fingers pull out those elegant serifs with a twirl and lift of my pen.  But that bottom serif on the C is more suited to chisel and hammer.

[image: representative glyphs]

Comment: Hi MMacD, we have some [requirements](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/2366) for font identification questions, please take a look and [edit] your question to include that information. Thanks!

Comment: um, I thought I did meet the requirements.  I provided a sample, including the distinctive characters that set it apart from others of its kind, mentioned that I found the font being used as drop caps in a book (Julie Garwood's *The Ideal Man*  mass-market paperback,  if it matters), and admitted that, to my surprise, I didn't recognise it or even know whether it's a named font.  What did I miss out?

Comment: From the requirements (the first point): "Detail what you've attempted already to try and identify your font" (which is followed by a list of font-id services).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like Waters Titling Pro Regular is a close match, if not the exact match:

[image]